# Random C/Objective-C questions

Tags: objective-c, c

I have come across a few lines of coding I do not understand, and would be grateful for clarification:

1. `if(!(counter&7))`
2. `ds->direction = ts->direction;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. if `counter` is a multiple of 8
2. set the `direction` element of `*ds` equal to the `direction` element of `*ts`

Answer (score 2):

The first checks if the result of a bitwise-AND on the counter with 7 is not zero, and the latter assigns the value of the `direction` member of one struct to the `direction` member of another.

Comment: Where "one struct" == "the struct pointed to by the pointer ds" and "another" == "the struct pointed to by the pointer ts".

Answer (score 1):

1) same as

1. `if (!(counter & 7))`
2. `if ((!(counter & 7)) != 0)`
3. `if ((counter & 7) == 0)`
4. if the lower 3 bits of counter are zero (or if counter is a multiple of 8)

2) same as

1. `(*ds).direction = (*ts).direction;`
2. set direction of `ds` (must be of a struct type) to direction of `ts`

Comment: In (1), I think the parenthesized part of step 4 is only correct if `counter` is unsigned...

Comment: It depends, I think, on representation. For sign and magnitude and two's complement, I think it holds (the three low bits being zero implies the number is a multiple of 8)

Comment: Indeed. Actually I'm curious what the standard says about signed bitwise operators. I couldn't find any language specific to signed or unsigned types so I assume they're required to operate bitwise on the representations.